# Как сделать чтобы загорались нижние кружочки на слайдере?

Tags: jquery, css

Как сделать чтобы в зависимости от слайда кружочки загорались?

https:// jsfiddle.net/7f5q44dg/ (пробел убрать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот небольшая подсказка, дописал пару строчек, теперь работает при пролистывании слайдов вперёд, а как назад сделать думаю разберешься дальше сам. Удачи

```
var slideNow = 1;
var slideCount = $('#slidewrapper').children().length;
var slideInterval = 3000;
var navBtnId = 0;
var translateWidth = 0;
$('.slide-nav-btn:eq('+(slideNow-1)+')').css('background', 'red');
$(document).ready(function() {
var switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);

$('#viewport').hover(function() {
    clearInterval(switchInterval);
}, function() {
    switchInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, slideInterval);
});

$('#next-btn').click(function() {
    nextSlide();
});

$('#prev-btn').click(function() {
    prevSlide();
});

$('.slide-nav-btn').click(function() {
    navBtnId = $(this).index();

    if (navBtnId + 1 != slideNow) {
        translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (navBtnId);
        $('#slidewrapper').css({
            'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        });
        slideNow = navBtnId + 1;
    }
   });
});


function nextSlide() {
$('.slide-nav-btn:eq('+slideNow+')').css('background', 'red');
$('.slide-nav-btn:eq('+(slideNow-1)+')').css('background', 'white');
if (slideNow == slideCount || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
  $('.slide-nav-btn:eq('+(slideNow-4)+')').css('background', 'red');
    $('#slidewrapper').css('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
    slideNow = 1;
} else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',

    });

    slideNow++;
   }
}

function prevSlide() {
if (slideNow == 1 || slideNow <= 0 || slideNow > slideCount) {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideCount - 1);
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });
    slideNow = slideCount;
} else {
    translateWidth = -$('#viewport').width() * (slideNow - 2);
   $('.slide-nav-btn:eq('+slideNow+')').css('background', 'red');
    $('#slidewrapper').css({
        'transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translate(' + translateWidth + 'px, 0)',
    });

    slideNow--;

}
}
```